# Is there a way to extract time from a string literal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a varchar column that contains this data `"Mon, 11 Nov 2019 12:00:00 +0800"`. what I want is to select only the time which is `12:00:00`.

ex:

```
select 'Last Updated on Mon, 11 Nov 2019 12:00:00 +0800'
```

it should return the time which `"12:00:00"`

is there a function in sql to solve this?

this is my sample raw data
[image]

Comment: What rdbms you're working with?

Comment: I'm using ms sql server

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to provide some more data? It's kinda hard to answer based on a single string.

Comment: how do you extract `12:00:00` from `Nov 11 2019, 12:45 pm +08` ? What happen to the minutes ? How about the `am / pm` ?

Comment: i can disregard the am / pm using this column "observation_time_rfc822" which has 24hour format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you don't have seconds on your sample, I believe its default to `:00`. Using `Patindex` and `substring` will do the trick.

```
declare @str varchar(max) = 'Last Updated on Nov 11 2019, 12:45 pm +08'

select concat(substring(@str, patindex('%[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]%'
    , @str), 5), ':00')
```

**output:**

[image]

**or** to ignore `minutes` and `seconds`

```
select concat(substring(@str, patindex('%[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]%'
        , @str), 2), ':00:00')
```

**output:**

[image]

if will take `am/pm` into consideration. `cast` it to `time`.

```
  select cast(concat(substring(@str, patindex('%[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]%'
            , @str), 2), ':00:00', substring(@str,  patindex('%[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]%', @str) + 6, 2)) as time)
```

Comment: this does not distinguish between `'8:45 pm'` and `'8:45 am'`

Comment: @PatrickArtner, OP just want to extract the time, didn't ask whether its AM or PM

Comment: i tried your script but i got some weird result like this "Last:00"

Comment: try selecting this "Fri, 8 Nov 2019 21:30:00 +0800"

Comment: based on your updated requirement you only need this. `select concat(substring(@str, patindex('%[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]%'
        , @str), 2), ':00:00')`

Comment: with minutes po

Comment: @Meraki, with minutes `select concat(substring(@str, patindex('%[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]%'
         , @str), 5), ':00')`

Comment: @METAL thank you sir working on column "observation_time"

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @str varchar(max) = 'Last Updated on Nov 11 2019, 1:45 pm +08';

select LTRIM(substring(@str, patindex('%[01 ][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]%', @str), 5)+':00');
```

Try this. It covers the case when hour is less than 10 i.e. in single digits.